# Let $R$ be a local ring with a nilpotent maximal ideal $M$ and $I\subseteq M$. Then $ya\in I$ implies $ya=0$ for some $0\neq y\in R$

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a local ring with a nilpotent maximal ideal $M$.   If $I\subseteq M$ is a fixed ideal for which a fixed element $a\in R$, $a+I\neq I$. Prove that  for any $0\neq y\in R$ and $y\notin I$,  $ya\in I$ implies $ya=0$.

My attempt is:

$a+I\neq I$ implies that $a\notin I$. But $ya\in I$ for some $y\in R$ implies that $Ra\subseteq I$ (where $Ra$ is a left ideal generated by $a$), which means that $a\in I$, and this is a contradiction.

Is that reasoning right?

Comment: "$ya\in I$ implies $ya=0$ for some   $0\neq y\in R$."  This is very unclear because the quantification for $y$ is undecipherable. Implicitly, "$ya\in I$ means "There exists a $y$ such that $ya\in I$" but then to go on and say "then $ya=0$ for some $y\in R$" constitutes *another* quantification over the same variable. What do you mean?

Comment: I have made some amendments on $y$.

Comment: With your amendment, this statement is not going to work. For example, if $I=M$, then $I$ is prime, so $ya\in I$ means one of $y$ or $a$ is already in $I$,  which is inconsistrent with $a\notin I$ and $y\notin I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample : take $R=k[x]/(x^3)$ which is local with nilpotent maximal ideal $(x)$, take $I=(x^2)$, then for $a=y=x$ you have $ay=x^2\in I$, $a+I\neq I$ and $y\notin I$, but $ay\neq 0$